# Questions on phone contacts and Google contacts

Tags: contacts

I am using 7562 Samsung S Duos.

I merged all the phonebook numbers to my Google account. Those numbers are not shown in phone book, but are shown in the Google account in my phone.

- How do I copy all the numbers to the phonebook?
- Where are the numbers actually stored now? Is it in Google server or is it in my phone only?
- What will happen to these numbers if I log out my Google account from my Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Contacts. Press contacts to display, then select which merged contact you want to display. Or, select all contacts. You can also customise the contacts to display.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove Unnecessary Contacts, take a backup contacts to SD Card using the
  option >> back up to SDCard/Storage or something similar. 
  Delete all your contacts, then Import form SD Card, you will get an
  option to select to which the contacts has to be saved. Select Phone
  and you are done.
- Your contacts are always stored in your phone, at `/data/data/android.providers.contacts` a copy of it is stored in your Google Account when you sync. Remember the contacts that are under `Google` only will get synced.
- Nothing will happen when you log out from your Google account. Only Auto Sync is off.